# Which PHP function can I use instead of <?=

Tags: php, templates, yii2

I have found code in view like so:

```php
<?php if ($condition->isTrue()): ?>
    <?= Html::a('label', ['/location'], ['title' => 'some title']) ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I'm certain that it is possible to make it single PHP block (like there is just one start/end PHP tag. The question is: what would be appropirate replacement for the `<?=` tag? Can it be anything that produce an output or is there some best practice?

Comment: `<?=` = `<?php echo` - see here https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: `echo` ???  ? ???

Comment: You could echo a ternary expression if you like. `<?= $condition->isTrue() ? Html::a('label', ['/location'], ['title' => 'some title']) : '' ?>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this

```
<?php 
if ($condition->isTrue()) {
    echo Html::a('label', ['/location'], ['title' => 'some title']);
}
?>
```

What you was looking for was PHP tags. The `<?php` & `?>` tags are for executable PHP code. The `<?=` tag is similar to `<?php echo ...`.

Some docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: Lol, thanks, I did not know `<?=` is actually native PHP, I've never used it